# R list/table manipulation replacing "for" loop with sapply?

Tags: r

I am attempting in R to just add a simple constant to a column of a table with e.g.

```
dim(exampletable)
[1] 3900    2
```

to add a value on the second column, what I do and works is:

```
newtable <- exampletable
for (i in 1:nrow(newtable)){newtable[i,2] <- exampletable[i,2] + constant}
```

but this seems a bit overkill. Is there a more elegant way to do it with, say sapply?

Thanks, Johannes

Comment: Yes!!!! `newtable[,2] <- newtable[,2] + constant`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R is vectorised and has very handy syntax for operations that tend to be more verbose in other languages. What you have described is possibly the *worst* implementation of what you want to do, and pretty much the antithesis of what R is about. Instead, use R's inbuilt vectorisation and live a happy long life!

There are so many ways to do this, but the canonical way (excepting the use of column index integers rather than column names) is:

```
newtable[,2] <- newtable[,2] + constant
```

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame( x = 1:3 )
df$y <- df$x + 1
df
#  x y
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#3 3 4
```

I recommend reading up on the basics of R. There are several good tutorials on [**the info page**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) of the `r` tag.

Comment: thank you for the answer, even though a very late thanks. This was what I thought it should more look like!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Dummy data
exampletable <- data.frame(x=runif(3900), y=runif(3900))
#Define new constant
MyConstant <- 10
#Make newtable with MyConstant update
newtable <- exampletable
newtable$y <- newtable$y + MyConstant
```

This is basics of R language, read some manuals.